# Multiple Image Upload Maintaining Selection Order-Multer[node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sorting, multer

I want to get the order of images uploaded using multer according to the order which the user selected before dragging. Is it possible?

```
 exports.summaryPost =   (req, res) => {
upload (req,  res,  (err) => {   
      if(err) {
        res.send(err)
      }
       else {
        const filez = req.files
        var files = []
        
        for(const file of [...req.files])  {
          files.push({imageName: file.filename});
        }          
     
      }
  })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
const filez = req.files
            var files = []

            for(const file of [...req.files])  {

              files.push({imageName: file.filename});

             }
             const collator = new Intl.Collator();
              files.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.imageName, b.imageName));

            console.log(files)
```